# Merge sort in python: slicing vs iterating - impact on complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity, mergesort

I want to check that my understanding of how python handles slices is correct.

Here's my implementation of merge sort:

```
def merge_sort(L):
    def merge(a, b):
        i, j = 0, 0
        c = []
        while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
            if a[i] < b[j]:
                c.append(a[i])
                i += 1
            elif b[j] < a[i]:
                c.append(b[j])
                j += 1
        if a[i:]:
            c.extend(a[i:])
        if b[j:]:
            c.extend(b[j:])
        return c

    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    else:
        mid = len(L) // 2
        left = merge_sort(L[:mid])
        right = merge_sort(L[mid:])
        return merge(left, right)
```

Am I right in thinking that I could replace this:

```
if a[i:]:
    c.extend(a[i:])
if b[j:]:
    c.extend(b[j:])
```

With this:

```
while i < len(a):
    c.append(a[i])
    i += 1
while j < len(b):
    c.append(b[j])
    j += 1
```

And have the exact same level of complexity? My understanding of slicing is that its complexity is equivalent to slice length? Is that correct?

Does the fact that I'm calling a slice twice (first in the condition, second time inside of it) make it 2x complexity?

Comment: You're right that slicing is O(n), but extending once is almost surely faster than appending multiple times because multiple calls to append may require multiple memory reallocations, which is costly compared to the (presumably) single allocation used by extend. You are correct that you should cache the slice in a variable to avoid doing it multiple times.

Comment: And since you know the length of the final list, you should probably preallocate and assign in indices instead of appending

Comment: 2 is a constant factor, so it may take twice as long but it's the same complexity class. In any case, you don't have to actually check. You can just do `c.extend(a[i:])` since extending with an empty sequence simply does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `mergesort` has problems:

- in the `merge` function's main loop, you do nothing if the values in `a[i]` and `b[j]` are equal, or more precisely if you have neither `a[i] < b[i]` nor `a[i] > b[i]`. This causes an infinite loop.
- there is no need to define `merge` as a local function, actually there is no need to make it a separate function, you could inline the code and save the overhead of a function call.

Here is a modified version:

```py
def merge_sort(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    else:
        mid = len(L) // 2
        a = merge_sort(L[:mid])
        b = merge_sort(L[mid:])
        i, j = 0, 0
        c = []
        while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
            if a[i] <= b[j]:
                c.append(a[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                c.append(b[j])
                j += 1
        if a[i:]:
            c.extend(a[i:])
        else:
            c.extend(b[j:])
        return c
```

Regarding performance, slicing or iterating has no impact on complexity since both operations have linear time cost.

Regarding performance, here are directions to try:

- replace the test `if a[i:]` with `if i < len(a)`. Creating the slice twice is costly.
- perform the sort in place, avoiding the `append` operations
- restructure the main loop to have a single test per iteration

Here is a modified version:

```py
def merge_sort(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    else:
        mid = len(L) // 2
        a = merge_sort(L[:mid])
        b = merge_sort(L[mid:])
        i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
        while True:
            if a[i] <= b[j]:
                L[k] = a[i]
                k += 1
                i += 1
                if (i == len(a)):
                    L[k:] = b[j:]
                    return L
            else:
                L[k] = b[j]
                k += 1
                j += 1
                if (j == len(b)):
                    L[k:] = a[i:]
                    return L
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you! Why is performing sort in place better than appending?

Comment: Sorting in place saves allocating a new list in the merge phase. You can do this if you do not need to keep the original list in its original order.